# mirror an mpmovieplayercontroller to tvout

Tags: video, ios, overlay, screenshot, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am looking for a way of mirroring videos to the TVOut on an iTouch, not in fullscreen. For my code, I have used Rob Terrell's screen mirroring example here: http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/123
and this one as well:
http://www.e-string.com/content/screen-mirroring-ipad

I have used `image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();` to take screen shots of my app to then mirror out to an external display. I CAN mirror everything in my app using `UIScreen -screens`', but as soon as any `MpMoviePlayercontroller` video is played, it shows up black on the external display. I'm guessing that perhaps `MpMoviePlayercontroller`uses video overlay and that it is not being captured? anyone have any knowledge on this?

I have embedded a custom view in which `MpMoviePlayercontroller` plays a video in a small portion of the window and it is the only thing not being shown on an external screen, can someone point me in the direction to accomplish having the video also show up? Should I look at `AVFoundation` or a way to play a video in `UIWebView` (not full screen) or will this still lead me to the same problem?